# rails3 monkey-patch generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, generator, monkeypatching

I want to monkey-patch the rspec-rails generator to generates a _form.html_spec.rb template. I know how do that, but not where I should put this patch!

What I've done:

```
# rspec_generator_patch.rb
module Rspec
  module Generators
    class ScaffoldGenerator < Base
      def generate_views_specs_with_form *args, &block
        generate_views_specs_without_form
        copy_view :_form
      end
      alias_method_chain :generate_views_specs, :form
    end
  end
end
```

Where I put this file? Thank you.

EDIT:

Ok, I think problem is almost solved. Instead of monkey-patch, I've inherited the specific generators and edited the method. There's the solution:

```
# lib/generators/rspec_modded/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb
require 'generators/rspec/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb'
module RspecModded
  module Generators
    class ScaffoldGenerator < Rspec::Generators::ScaffoldGenerator
      def generate_view_specs
        super
        copy_view :_form
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If I do `rails g` rspec_modded:scaffold is in list and actually work if called manually (`rails g rspec_modded:scaffold test`).

```
# config/application.rb
# ...
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :rspec_modded, :fixture => false, fixture_replacement: nil
  g.fallbacks[:rspec_modded] = :rspec
end
```

For what I know, every `hook_for :test_framework` should call rspec_modded generator and rspec should manage the rest (fallbacks). But it doesn't work: for some reason the unit_test generator kick in! What the matter? I really don't understand...

Answer (score 0):

You can put your monkey patch anywhere, as long as it gets loaded. With rails, you'd usually put it in the /lib folder.

Comment: That's the problem. What files are loaded when scaffold generator run?

Comment: I think it loads the basic enviroment (script/rails). But you must know, /lib isn't loaded by default and if you set it to auto-load then it will never get loaded probably. So you need to put a require somewhere explicitly